# Encoding ASCII in c++ for android application

Tags: android, c++, ascii, extended-ascii

I have some C++ code that I use in my android application. It takes a string and converts each character to an int from this [ascii table](https://www.ascii-code.com/). I then renders the correct glyph based on this.
It works on most of the devices I tested a few different google pixels and samsung phones, but when I test in a 3.3" WQVGA emulator on api 24 - 30 it doesn't function properly.

I imagine I'm going at this all wrong. Is there a better way of doing this? Is there a fix to my code?

Thanks for your time.

```
void text::drawtexthorizontal( double x, double y, int textheight, string textin)
{
  int n = textin.length(); 
  // declaring character array 
  char char_array[n + 1]; 
  // copying the contents of the string to char array 
  strcpy(char_array, textin.c_str()); 
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){ 
    //get ascii or "extended" ascii index and store it in symbol
    int symbol;
    if( (char_array[i] & ( 1 << 7 )) >> 7 == 1){
      if( (char_array[i] & ( 1 << 6 )) >> 6 == 1){
        //comb takes 2 byte representation and returns an int between 128 and 255 corresponding to extended ascii
        symbol = comb(int(char_array[i]),int(char_array[i+1]));
        i++;
      }
      else{
        symbol = comb(int(char_array[i+1]),int(char_array[i]));
        i++;
      }
    } 
    else symbol = int(char_array[i]);

    //render chars[symbol]
  }
}


int text::comb( int n, int m){
/*https://naveenr.net/unicode-character-set-and-utf-8-utf-16-utf-32-encoding/ for 2 byte encoding*/
  int a[8] = { 0 },b[8] = { 0 };;
  int i,k=0; 
  for (i = 0; n > 0; i++) { 
     a[i] = n % 2; 
     n /= 2; 
  }

  for (i = 0; m > 0; i++){ 
     b[i] = m % 2; 
     m /= 2; 
  }

  for (i = 4; i >=0 ; i--){
    k = 10 * k + a[i];
  }

  for (i = 5; i >=0 ; i--){
    k = 10 * k + b[i];
  }

  int dec_value = 0; 
// Initializing base value to 1, i.e 2^0 
  int base = 1; 
  int temp = k; 
  while (temp) { 
    int last_digit = temp % 10; 
    temp = temp / 10; 
    dec_value += last_digit * base; 
    base = base * 2; 
  } 
  
  if(dec_value > 255) dec_value = 32;
  return dec_value; 

}
```

Comment: Using _one_ of the extended ASCII tables in 2020 = fail, unless you target a very specific market.

Comment: I'm really confused as to why you'd need to do *any* encoding here. UTF-8 exists and is a superset of 7-bit ASCII.

Comment: That table you've linked to is not "ASCII", but [Windows-1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252), an obsolete 8-bit encoding for *some* European languages. Can you convert your text to UTF-8 and forget about all of this?

Comment: Ok I'll look into UTF-8 encoding. Sorry for the noob question.

Comment: Nothing wrong with asking questions. We're just trying to help you avoid a whole world of hurt. If you can be UTF-8 out of the gate a *lot* of problems just go away.

Comment: I do not understand what this code is doing. Can you explain it?

Comment: Now is the time to upgrade your embedded application for 16-bit characters.  It will save you time later on.  See also UTF-16.